Discontinuous solutions of a functional equation involving n-simplices
Question

For all non-zero natural number $n$, find all functions $f :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for any non-degenerated $n$-simplex $A_0, ..., A_n$:$$ f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n A_i \right) = \prod_{i=0}^{n} f(A_i)$$


I didn't manage to determine discontinuous solutions of this equation when $n$ is even.
Proof : $f(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq \{-1,1\}$ or $f$ is the zero function.
It is trivial that if $f$ vanishes then it is constant. 
Let $S$ be the set of solutions.
Take a regular $n$-simplex $p_0,...,p_n$ inscribed the unit $n$-sphere. Let $s_i = (n+1)p_i + \sum_{j \neq i, j = 0}^n -p_j$.
We have that $p_0,.., s_i,.. , p_n$ is a non degenerated $n$-simplex of center $p_i$ and $s_0,..,s_n$ is a non degenerated n simplex of center 0.
We then have:
$f(0) = \prod_{i = 0}^n f(p_i) = \prod_{i = 0}^n \left( f(s_i) \prod_{j \neq i, j = 0}^n f(p_j) \right) = \left(\prod_{i=0}^n f(s_i)\right) \left(\prod_{j=0}^n f(p_j)\right)^n = f(0)^{n+1}$
As $S$ is stable by right composition with a translation, $f(x)^n = 1$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This solves our equation for odd $n$
If $n$ is even, we still get : $$f(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq \{-1,1\}$$
We can now deduce that nonvanishing continuous solutions are constant to $1$ or constant to $-1$ when $n$ is even.

It is worth noting that a solution is entirely defined by it's values on an n-sphere.

Definitions: Let
$$
\mathcal G = \{(v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_n) \in (\mathbb R^n)^{n+1}:\{v_1-v_0,\ldots,v_n-v_0\} \text{ is a basis of } \mathbb R^n\}
$$
be the set of $(n+1)$-tuples of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ which form the vertices of a non-degenerate $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\mathcal S$ be the space of functions
$$
\mathcal S = \left\{f\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R\mid \prod_{i=0}^n f(v_i) = f \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n v_i \right), \forall (v_0,\ldots,v_n) \in \mathcal G\right\}.
$$
If $f \in \mathcal S$ has $f(v)=0$ for any $v \in \mathbb R^n$, then it follows immediately that $f(w)=0$ for all $w \in \mathbb R^n$, since if $w \neq v$ one can construct an $n$-simplex with $v$ as a vertex and $w$ as its barycentre. We therefore will assume from now on that $f(v) \neq 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$.
Claim 1: If $f \in \mathcal S$ then $f(v)f(-v) = C$ a constant for all non-zero vectors $v \in \mathbb R^n$.
Proof:
Let $H$ be a hyperplane (i.e. subspace of dimension $n-1$) in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $v_0 \in \mathbb R^n\backslash H$. Let $B_H=\{u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1}\}$ be a basis of $H$. Since $\{v,-v,u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1}\}$ is a non-degenerate $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^n$ we have
$$
f(v)f(-v)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(u_i) = f \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i \right)
$$
or equivalently:
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
f(v_0)f(-v_0) = f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i\right) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(u_i)^{-1}.
$$
Now the left-hand side of $(\dagger)$ depends on $v_0 \in \mathbb R^n \backslash H$, while the right-hand side depends on a choice of basis for $H$, and the equality holds for all such vectors $v_0$ and bases $B_H$. It follows that
$$
f(v)f(-v)=C_H=f \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}u_i \right)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(u_i)^{-1} $$
for some constant $C_H$ (possibly depending on $H$). But if we take $H_i = \{v \in \mathbb R^n: \langle v, e_i \rangle =0\}$ to be the coordinate hyperplanes, if $i \neq j$ then i) $H_i^c \cap H_j^c \neq \emptyset$ and
ii) $\bigcup H_i^c = \mathbb R^n \backslash \{0\}$.
Now $i)$ implies that $C_{H_i} = C_{H_j}$ and $ii)$ that if $v \neq 0$ then $f(v)f(-v)=C_{H_i}$ for some $i$. Thus we see that $f(v)f(-v)=C$ for some constant $C$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n\backslash\{0\}$.
Claim 2: $C = 1= f(0)^2$.
Considering the right-hand side of $(\dagger)$ we see that
$$
\tag{$\ddagger$}
f \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i \right) = C \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(u_i).
$$
Replacing $(u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1})$ with $(-u_1,\ldots,-u_{n-1}\}$ in $(\ddagger)$ gives
$$
C/f \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i \right) = f \left(-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i \right) = C\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f(-u_i) = C\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} C/f(u_i)
$$
which implies that
$$
C = C^n \cdot f \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i \right)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(u_i)^{-1} = C^n \cdot C,
$$
so that $C^n =1$ and hence $C \in \{\pm 1\}$.
Moreover, $(0,v_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1}) \in \mathcal G$ and hence
$$
f(0)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}f(v_i) = f \left(\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} v_i \right)
$$
and similarly
$$
f(0)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}f(-v_i) = f \left(-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} v_i \right).
$$
But now multiplying the previous two identities together and using the fact that $f(v)f(-v)=C$ for all nonzero $v \in \mathbb R^n$ where $C^n=1$ we find that $f(0)^2=C$. But then as $C = f(0)^2\geq 0$ we must have $C=1$ and $f(0)\in \{\pm 1\}$.
Claim 3: $\mathcal S$ has an action of the abelian group $(\mathbb R^n,+)$.
Proof: If $f \in \mathcal S$ and $u \in \mathbb R^n$, let $u(f)(v) = f(v+u)$. Then we have
$$
\prod_{i=0}^n u(f)(v_i) = \prod_{i=0}^n f(v_i+u) = f(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n (v_i+u)) = f\left(\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n v_i \right)+u \right) = u(f) \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n v_i \right),
$$
where we have used the fact that if $(v_0,\ldots,v_n) \in\mathcal G$ then so is $(v_0+u,\ldots,v_n+u)$ for any $u \in \mathbb R^n$.
Now we have seen that, if $f \in \mathcal S$ then $f(0)=\pm 1$. But for any $f \in \mathcal S$, $u\in \mathbb R^n$ we have $u(f)\in \mathcal S$ hence $u(f)(0) \in \{\pm 1\}$, and thus $f(u)\in \{\pm 1\}$ for all $u\in \mathbb R^n$. In the same way, we see that $f(u+v)f(u-v)=1$ for all $v\in \mathbb R^n\backslash\{0\}$. But any two vectors $v_1,v_2$ can be written in the form $v_1 = u+v$, $v_2 = u-v$ where $u=\frac{1}{2}(v_1+v_2)$ and $v = \frac{1}{2}(v_1-v_2)$, hence $f(v_1)f(v_2) =1$ whenever $v_1\neq v_2$, and $f(v)^2=1$ for all $v\in \mathbb R^n$. Thus $f(v)=\pm 1$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$, and $f(v)=-1$ for some $v \in \mathbb R^n$ implies $f(v)=-1$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$.
Finally, if $f(v)=-1$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$ then $(-1)^{n+1} \prod_{i=0}^{n} f(v_i) = f \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n v_i \right) =(-1)$ thus we must have $n$ even if $f(v)=-1$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$ is to be an element of $\mathcal S$. It follows that when $n$ is even, $\mathcal S = \{\pm 1\}$, the constant functions $+1$ and $-1$, while if $n$ is odd, $\mathcal S=\{1\}$ is just the constant function $1$.
